# Using open xml sdk code, how to resize a table (in ms word document) to fit into page margins?

Tags: .net, ms-word, openxml, wordprocessingml

I am using **Microsoft Open XML SDK** to generate a word document. I have used **Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool** for converting the word document into C# code, and thus I have created a wrapper class by encapsulating the table creation code. I have successfully generated word document.

> But the **issue is, some tables are expanding in their width beyondpage
>   margins.** I searched in google, and found that **GrowAutoFit class allows
>   Tables to AutoFit into page margins,** but I couldn't find the exact
>   usage of this class to implement the functionality.

**I searched a lot for many days before asking a question here, as i have read the terms of asking a question on this forum.** I got tired of searching, and i'm putting forward this query here. So please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the answer for my own question.**

> The reason for the tables extending out of page was that i had
>   set page margins as zero in the code. So, after i set the page margins
>   as 1 inch on all sides, the tables are not extending out of margins.
>
> Thanks to the **Office Open XML SDK Productivity tool**, which shows
>   the native XML code, and also the C# code when a word document is
>   opened in it. And becuase of this tool, i was able to figure out the
>   issue.

Thanks for your suggestions Maximilian :)